# Software recommendation question

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, vote-to-close

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639220/is-there-any-tcl-code-coverage-tool-for-eclipse) the user ask about what tools can solve a specific problem.
The possible answer for such a question leads usually to a list.

Many people believe that such a question is not a good question and vote to close it, while others [state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639220/is-there-any-tcl-code-coverage-tool-for-eclipse/15641968#comment22195400_15639220) that this is a good question.

According to the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) such a question is not disallowed, but the [about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) page states that you should not ask about

> - Product or service recommendations or comparisons
> - Requests for lists of things, polls, opinions, discussions, etc.

which is clearly the case here. Also see [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) about shopping recommendations.

To discuss this topic a few people have left a comment on that question, which are IMHO itself off-topic and should be better discussed here on MSO, so better discuss it here.

So is this question on-topic or off-topic and why?

---

To bring the discussion to meta I'll post a comment with a link to this question, off-topic as well but in my opinion a necessary evil.

Note: I'm not a 10k+ user on SO and can not vote to close, but I still love to keep things clean, so I ask that here.

Comment: One comment not a consensus make.

Comment: The question is a shopping recommendation; it has now been closed as Not Constructive.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The question itself is not well formed.  Even if this weren't a "List of X" question, the question still has other problems that run afoul of the FAQ:

- No practical problem that we know of to be solved.
- No context
- No effort on the part of the OP to explain (really anything)

It'd be really hard to have a 'good' question come from this without a lot more involvement by the OP.

Comment: Accepted because final closing vote.

Answer (score 2):

The question is off-topic. You already found all the relevant links and posts.

Just because it is not also explicitly mentioned in the FAQ doesn't make it on-topic.

<sub>We have a new SE site called [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) where such questions would be on-topic.</sub>